# Kendo UI Grid not showing data from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo UI Grid, that is supposed to show data loaded from an Entity Framework, linked to a SQL Database. Everything was working fine but suddenly the data stopped showing in the Grid.

So, I have:

Index.cshtml

```
    @(

      Html.Kendo().Grid<Localidade>()
        .Name("LocalidadesGrid")
        .Columns(
        column =>
        {
            column.Bound(e => e.nome).Title("Nome").Groupable(false).Width(70);
            column.Bound(e => e.cod_postal).Title("Código Postal").Groupable(false).Width(30);
            column.Command(command => {            command.Edit().Text("Editar").UpdateText("Guardar").CancelText("Cancelar"); 
                command.Destroy().Text("Remover"); }).Width(172);
        }
        )
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Criar Nova Localidade"))
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
        .Filterable()
        .Selectable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(page => 
            page.Refresh(true)
                .PageSizes(true)
                .PreviousNext(true)
                .Messages(m => m.ItemsPerPage("Localidades por página")
                            .Display("{0}-{1} de {2}")
                            .First("Primeira página")
                            .Last("Última página")
                            .Previous("Página anterior")
                            .Next("Página seguinte"))
        )
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .DataSource(
        datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)   
            .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.id); model.Field(p => p.id).Editable(false); })
            .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInLine_Create", "Localidades"))
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetLocalidades", "Localidades"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInLine_Update", "Localidades"))
            .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInLine_Destroy", "Localidades"))
            )
)
```

LocalidadesController.cs

```
private quest_geralEntities db = new quest_geralEntities();

    public ActionResult GetLocalidades([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(db.Localidade.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

It's giving me an Internal Server Error when calling GetLocalidades, from LocalidadesController. I've also tried to return a JsonResult instead of an ActionResult, but the error didn't get solved.

**EDIT:**

I'm getting this in the output:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1024) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1020) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xaf8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

Comment: Look at the details of the internal server error. Post the stack trace if possible.

Comment: I've edited the initial question with the output VS is giving me.

Comment: Do **var db = new quest_geralEntities();** inside the 'GetLocalidades' method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnally found a solution. Maybe it's not the best, but as far as I know it's working well.

Instead of passing the Model to the View, I'm sending an IEnumerable, containing all the models I want to bind to my grid, with the help of a ViewBag.

In my controller I bind the data to the ViewBag:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    db = new quest_geralEntities();

    ViewBag.localidades = db.Localidade.Select(localidade => new LocalidadeViewModel
    {
        id = localidade.id,
        nome = localidade.nome,
        cod_postal = localidade.cod_postal
    });

    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@(

 Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<LocalidadeViewModel>) ViewBag.localidades)
          .Name("grid")
)
```

PS. I've created a ViewModel to workaround a circular reference exception I was getting.

That way the data is shown correctly, and I'm still able to use all CRUD operations.

I hope it can help someone.